# How can the UltraChart of Infragistics do even better?

Tags: c#, charts, infragistics

I need to convince my management that we can do very nice plots using infragistics, up to know this is what I have:

[image: Ugly plot]

In order have that here is my code :

```
//Set the chart titles
ChartPureAlpha.TitleTop.Text = TickerName;

//Set Chart legend
this.ChartPureAlpha.Legend.Visible = true;
this.ChartPureAlpha.Legend.Location = LegendLocation.Right;
this.ChartPureAlpha.Legend.Margins.Left = 5;
this.ChartPureAlpha.Legend.Margins.Right = 10;
this.ChartPureAlpha.Legend.Margins.Top = 15;
this.ChartPureAlpha.Legend.Margins.Bottom = 90;
this.ChartPureAlpha.Legend.SpanPercentage = 15;

this.ChartPureAlpha.LineChart.TreatDateTimeAsString = false;
this.ChartPureAlpha.ChartType = ChartType.ScatterChart;
this.ChartPureAlpha.ScatterChart.ConnectWithLines = true;
//ChartPureAlpha.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
this.ChartPureAlpha.Axis.X.Labels.ItemFormatString = "<ITEM_LABEL:dd-MM-yyyy>";
this.ChartPureAlpha.Axis.X.Labels.SeriesLabels.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 25);
this.ChartPureAlpha.Axis.X.Labels.SeriesLabels.Visible = true;
this.ChartPureAlpha.Axis.X.Labels.SeriesLabels.OrientationAngle = 315;

//ChartPureAlpha.Axis.X.TickmarkInterval = 1;
//ChartPureAlpha.Axis.X.TickmarkIntervalType = AxisIntervalType.Days;
//ChartPureAlpha.Axis.X.TickmarkStyle = AxisTickStyle.DataInterval;
// axis label
//ChartPureAlpha.TitleBottom.Text = "Date";
//ChartPureAlpha.TitleBottom.HorizontalAlign = StringAlignment.Center;
//ChartPureAlpha.TitleLeft.Text = "Raw Alpha)";
//ChartPureAlpha.TitleLeft.HorizontalAlign = StringAlignment.Center;

// Create and add series
ChartPureAlpha.Series.Add(dowjones);
```

I want to know how to :

- reduce marker size
- have the whole date (not truncated)
- change the label font

Comment: Nope, you need to learn that there is something called "documentation" (look up the term in a dictionary" that you can "read". All that is fully documetned. Or maybe you need another job - one that does not involve programming? Voted to close - this is a homework level question.

Answer (score 3):

Infragistics is already trying quite hard to advertise their charts, so why don't you just reuse [their marketing material](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/winforms/winchart.aspx#Gallery) ?

Answer (score 2):

After a few looking through the official 2011.2 [infragistics help](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2011.2/CLR2.0/) i found some issues for you:

- reduce marker size: use the `IconSize Property` (Auto, Large, Medium, Small)
- change the label font:
  `this.ultraChart1.TitleTop.Font = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Underline, GraphicsUnit.Point);`
- have the whole date (not truncated):
   If the label is "My Text" and the Date is 5/10/2005 it would format the label as follows:
   `"<ITEM_LABEL><DATA_VALUE:MMM-dd-yyyy>" = MyText May 10, 2005`

hope that helps